# What is the meaning of {{strs[0}} and how does it work?

Tags: c++

I came accross this code on leetcode, but I am not getting how {{strs[0]}} works (Line no. 6)

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<string>> groupAnagrams(vector<string>& strs) {
        // Base case
        if(strs.size() == 1)
            return {{strs[0]}};
        
        vector<vector<string>> ans;
        unordered_map<string, vector<string>> M;
        for(int  i = 0; i < strs.size(); i++)
        {
            string str = strs[i];
            sort(strs[i].begin(), strs[i].end()); // Sorting the string
            M[strs[i]].push_back(str);  // Sorted string is the key and the value is the initial string
        }
        for(auto i = M.begin(); i != M.end(); i++)
            ans.push_back(i -> second);  // Traversing the map and adding the vectors of string to ans
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: It's a constructor of a vector of vectors (return type), where the inner vector is initialized with one element. The first string in the input

Comment: It's a short form of `return vector<vector<string>>{{strs[0]}};`. In a return statement it is pretty obvious that you want to construct the function's returned type, so you don't have to repeat that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strs` is a `vector` of `string`s, where `strs[0]` is the 1st string.

The function returns a `vector` of `vector`s of `string`s.

In the syntax  `{{strs[0]}}`, the outer `{}` represents the outer `vector`. Inside of the `{}` is a comma-separated list of the `vector`'s elements. Since the element type of the outer `vector` is another `vector`, each  element is wrapped in its own`{}`.  In this case, there is 1 element.  And the element type of the inner `vector` is a `string`.

So, the `return` statement is returning a `vector` that holds 1 `vector` that holds the value of `strs[0]`.

From a more technical perspective, each `{}` is converted by the compiler into a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) that is then passed to `std::vector`'s [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). So, the `return` statement in question is *roughly* equivalent (not quite) to the following:

```cpp
std::string tempStr = strs[0];

std::initializer_list<std::string> init1(&tempStr, 1);
std::vector<std::string> tempVec1(init1);

std::initializer_list<std::vector<std::string>> init2(&tempVec1, 1);
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> tempVec2(init2);

return tempVec2;
```